# IF, ELIF e ELSE

Tags: python, if, else

Estou dando meus primeiros passos em Python, e me surgiu uma dúvida na sentença if/else, tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

"Tendo como dados de entrada a altura e o sexo de uma pessoa, construa um algoritmo que calcule seu peso ideal, utilizando as seguintes fórmulas:

Para homens: (72.7*h) - 58

Para mulheres: (62.1*h) - 44.7 (h = altura)

Peça o peso da pessoa e informe se ela está dentro, acima ou abaixo do peso."

Essa foi a lógica utilizada por mim:

```
def main():

altura = float(input("Digite a altura do paciente: "))
sexo = input("Digite o sexo do paciente, H(Masculino) ou F(Feminino): ")


altura
if sexo == H or sexo == h:
    peso = (72.7 * altura) - 58
    print ("O peso ideal do paciente é: ",peso)
    
    elif sexo == F or sexo == f:
        peso = (62.1 * altura) - 44.7
        print ("O peso ideal da paciente é: ",peso)
        
        else:
            print ("Sexo inválido")


pesopaciente = input("Digite o seu peso: ")

if pesopaciente < peso:
    print("Você está abaixo do peso ideal.")
    
    elif pesopaciente > peso:
        print("Você está acima do peso ideal.")
        
        else:
        print("Você está na média de peso.")
        

main()
```

Porém, o mesmo retorna o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "python", line 12
>
> elif sexo == F or sexo == f:
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você coloca `sexo == H` ele entende que você está se referindo à variável `H`. Coloque entre aspas, assim: `sexo == "H" or sexo == "h"`

Além disso a indentação está toda errada. O conteúdo da função `main` não está indentado, e o `elif` e o `else` devem estar na mesma coluna que o `if`.

Leia este artigo:

[Indentação em python](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Conceitos_b%C3%A1sicos/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Eu não tenho python 3 comigo pra testar, apenas o 2.7... mas acredito que esse código irá funcionar:

```
def main():
    altura = float(input("Digite a altura do paciente: "))
    sexo = input("Digite o sexo do paciente, H(Masculino) ou F(Feminino): ")

    if sexo == "H" or sexo == "h":
        peso = (72.7 * altura) - 58
        print ("O peso ideal do paciente é: ",peso)
    elif sexo == "F" or sexo == "f":
        peso = (62.1 * altura) - 44.7
        print ("O peso ideal da paciente é: ",peso)
    else:
        print ("Sexo inválido")

    pesopaciente = input("Digite o seu peso: ")

    if pesopaciente < peso:
        print("Você está abaixo do peso ideal.")
    elif pesopaciente > peso:
        print("Você está acima do peso ideal.")
    else:
        print("Você está na média de peso.")

main()
```

Comment: Realmente, minha indentação estava completamente errada. Estou meio acostumado com Java, não tinha noção de que era necessário ser desta forma. Se você puder me tirar outra dúvida, assim que eu apliquei as correções que você me passou, notei que também é necessário dar um tab na linha pesopaciente = input("Digite o seu peso: "), você saberia me dizer o por que?
Muito obrigado, Filipe!

Comment: Por que ele está dentro do `main`. Se você tirasse ele da indentação, tanto a linha que tem diz `pesopaciente = input("Digite o seu peso: ")` quanto o resto do if estariam fora do main, o que não é o que você quer, acredito...

Answer (score -1):

Para além de corrigir o problema de indentação e aspas, deverá utilizar a função `raw_input()`, em vez da função `input()` simples. Ao utilizar a função `input()`, o utilizador deverá escrever "h" (com as aspas) para que o programa reconheça o caractere como sendo uma string.

A função `input()` reconhece o input do utilizador como sendo código Python. Ou seja, ao inserir apenas h (sem aspas), o python tentaria avaliar essa variável, que não existe no seu programa.

A função raw_input(), por sua vez, devolve a sequencia de caracteres ASCII inseridos pelo utilizador antes de premir ENTER, sendo esta sequencia de caracteres interpretada como uma string.

Comment: Cara, ele tá usando python 3, que não tem `raw_input`, apenas `input`. Se a sua resposta é derivada da minha podia ter escrito como comentário na minha resposta.